# How to define own group action in GAP?

Tags: group-actions, gap

I am beginner in [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org/). I have a group and a set. I wish to define an action the group on the set in my own way and wish to calculate its orbits and stabilizers. Is it possible? What is process?

Comment: See [Basic Actions](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html#X81B8F9CD868CD953) Section from the "Group Actions" Chapter of the GAP Manual: "If one needs an action for which no acting function is provided by the library it can be implemented via a GAP function that conforms to the syntax `actfun( omega, g )` where `omega` is an element of the action domain, `g` is an element of the acting group, and the return value is the image of `omega` under `g`. Please let me know if this helps, I may post a proper answer later.

Comment: @AlexanderKonovalov I have also tried to post this question in Gap Forum two times but failed since it shows [forum bounce](http://mail.gap-system.org/mailman/confirm/forum/99fa85d1c6a472b7b1dc72285f6811db4dfe2514). I shall send a private mail regarding this question in detail. thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am posting a CW answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue. This is just a quote from the GAP manual:

GAP already provides acting functions for the more common actions of a group. For built-in operations such as `Stabilizer` special methods are available for many of these actions.

If one needs an action for which no acting function is provided by the library it can be implemented via a GAP function that conforms to the syntax

```
actfun( omega, g )
```

where `omega` is an element of the action domain, `g` is an element of the acting group, and the return value is the image of `omega` under `g`.

For example one could define the following function that acts on pairs of polynomials via `OnIndeterminates`:

```
OnIndeterminatesPairs:= function( polypair, g )
  return [ OnIndeterminates( polypair[1], g ),
           OnIndeterminates( polypair[2], g ) ];
end;
```

Note that this function must implement a group action from the right. This is not verified by GAP and results are unpredictable otherwise.

Comment: See also another example here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1219961/

Comment: What is a CW answer? Is it different than an ( ordinary ) answer? When should an answer be a CW answer?

Comment: @niloderoock see https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki/. I reckon that time I just pasted text from the manual and did not want to score any points for it.