# Higher Level Group Actions beyond OnSets

Tags: abstract-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, gap

Is there a way to produce an orbit of a chain in a poset (whose elements are sets of sets) (that is, the group action is a group acting on the order complex of a poset)?

I really want something that looks like this:

`G.orbit(Z[0], action = "OnSetsSetsSets")` or perhaps `OnTuplesSetsSets`

Is there a workaround where I might be able to use just `OnSets`? Perhaps using lambda in some way?

Comment: See [BasicActions](http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap41.html#X81B8F9CD868CD953) - is lists `OnPoints`, `OnRight`, `OnLeftInverse`, `OnSets`, `OnTuples`, `OnPairs `, `OnSetsSets`, `OnSetsDisjointSets`, `OnSetsTuples`, `OnTuplesSets`, `OnTuplesTuples`, `OnLines`, `OnIndeterminates`, `Permuted`, `OnSubspacesByCanonicalBasis`, and also explains the syntax of a GAP function to implement an action if is not one of these.

Comment: P.S. see also [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509769/how-to-define-own-group-action-in-gap/532952#532952).

Comment: in the cloudsage interface, how do I create a cell to implement my own GAP function?

Comment: if you can enter any input in GAP command line, you can enter a function too: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/tut/chap4.html

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before, you could implement your own function. (Call `Print(OnSetsSets)` to get an idea how a putative `OnSetsSetsSets` etc. would have to look like.) However at some point you pay a price in time and memory for the indirections.

What I would do is to create an action of the group on sets of sets. For example (say the sets of sets can be seeded with orbits of a and b):

```
gap> g:=TransitiveGroup(8,20);;
gap> a:=[[1,3,5],[2,4,8]];;b:=[[1,2,7,8],[3,5]];;
gap> domain:=Orbit(g,a,OnSetsSets);;
gap> domain:=Union(domain,Orbit(g,b,OnSetsSets));;Length(domain);
32
gap> act:=ActionHomomorphism(g,domain,OnSetsSets,"surjective"); 
<action homomorphism>
gap> h:=Image(act);
```

Then every sets of sets is an element of `domain` and thus a number for `h`. A chain would be a set of such numbers and you could get orbits by letting `h` act `OnSets`, using `domain` to translate back to your original representation.

Concerning you comment question about `cloudsage` I have no clue, never having used it. Installing GAP is not hard and probably worth doing if you have any nontrivial calculation, rather than relying on a cloud platform.